# Linear algebra with matrices not only for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I haven't taken a course on Linear Algebra, but I kind of used the concepts of row/column vectors, matrices a lot. But somehow only with respect with the $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector space. When talking about other vector spaces, like a function space, do matrices (and implicitly column/row vectors) have that great impact?

My intuition says yes, because:

1. In $\mathbb{R}^3$:

   Let $B = \{e_1=(1,0,0),e_2=(0,1,0),e_3=(0,0,1)\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, where (a,b,c) is a 3-tuple

   Then:
   $[(1,2,3)]_B = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$
2. In the function space of polynomials:

   Let $B = \{1,x,x^2\}$ be a basis

   Then:
   $[1+2x+3x^2]_B = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$.

Are these considerations useful or good to be kept in mind when working with linear algebra? I mean, is it important not to forget about matrices when turning from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to another vector space?

Comment: Yes, it is very important. As you note, using bases and hence coordinate vectors in the general vector space, a lot of questions can be answered using the theory developed for $R^n $ or even $n $-tuples over a generic field, and matrices over that field

Comment: Matrices can be used for any *finite dimensional* vector space over any field ($\mathbf Q, \mathbf C$ for instance), and even for any finitely generated *free module* over any commutative ring (modules are the structure corresponding to vector spaces when working over a ring instead of a field).

Comment: @Bernard Curiosity: you can actually drop the requirement that $R$ is commutative, but the opposite ring $R^{\rm op}$ starts popping up. There are a couple of results in this direction in Adkins & Weintraub's *Algebra: An Approach via Module Theory*, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Also, that importance to matrices is given because there is the concept of _basis_, right?